# How do I access a Form's ComboBox selectedItem from a C# Program

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I could have sworn I had this working on an earlier version of my program, but now I can't seem to get it to work.

On my form I have a ComboBox, and I want the value that the user selects to be accessible globally (on another C# program), so that I can use it to modify configuration settings of my serial port. What I'd like is something like what is below, how would I modify my form, and create a global variable to make this work? Thank you in advance

Also for what it's worth, I did check a variety of different threads on Stack and other forums, and try some of the suggestions but I keep getting errors in my compiler

```
SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy way:

```
SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(Convert.ToInt32(ComPortComboBox.SelectedText));
```

Comment: To improve your answer, try explaining what the line of code does.

Comment: thank you for your feedback Mohsen, unfortunately I did not clarify the extent of my problem ,and this does not cover the issue, but a great solution nonetheless and awarded top answer

Answer (score 1):

The `SerialPort` constructor expects a string. `SelectedItem` is an `object`. No doubt the error you're getting is something along the lines of:

```
cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
```

So convert the selected combobox item to a string:

```
SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(Convert.ToInt32(ComPortComboBox.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

`SerialPort` class has 2 overloads with 1 argument . One of them takes an `IContainer` and the other one takes a `string` and `ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem` returns an `object`. So if you want to use the second constructor, you have to cast the selected item to a `string`.

So you have two choices:

1. Use `SelectedItem`, but you need to convert it to `string`:

   ```
   SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
   ```
2. Use `Text`, it returns the selected item as a `string` by self:

   ```
   SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(ComPortComboBox.Text);
   ```